# How can I run Just Cause 2 on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, directx

I have Just Cause 2 installed on Windows XP. I also install DirectX10 on it. So the only thing I need is a new EXE that don't ask for Windows XP. Do you know were can I find one?

Comment: gaming questions are offtopic on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you think you installed DX 10 on XP, but you didn't. The highest DX that you can run on XP is 9.

Comment: There is a crack version of DirectX 10 for XP. google before...

Comment: @Domingo - I am aware of it and I am also aware that is it incredibly buggy and unsupported. Because of this, there is no way of ruling it out as a problem for any issues you encounter. Maybe you should upgrade before...

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP can only run up to Direct X 9.  You would need windows vista or higher to run a DirectX 10 application.

The only way you could get it to work is to set the application to run in DirectX 9 mode.  This will vary on the application though and not always possible.  It might be time to upgrade your OS.

Comment: There is a crack version of DirectX 10 for XP. google before...

Comment: @Domingo I will not endorse cracked versions of software.  I gave you the official answer on why this will not work.  If this is about finding cracked software, then I will close this question immediately.

Comment: it's a gaming question and should've been closed immediately anyway.  :)